# installation of the symfony framework

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, xampp

I just started with the symfony framework I installed the environment without problem but when I run the symfony server for the first time with: symfony server: start I get an error like this

```
[Web server] [07-Apr -2021 06:27:42 Europe / Berlin] 2021-04-07T06: 27: 42 + 02: 00 [critical] Error not caught: syntax error, "|" unexpected, expected variable (T_VARIABLE)
and this |ERROR | SERVER GET (500) / ip="127.0.0.1"
```

here are the errors obtained need help please
[image][image]
I do not know what to do

Thank you!

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: You should to check your php version

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is the PHP version as well, because the Stack Trace shows a syntax error for the union types syntax (https://php.watch/versions/8.0/union-types) featured in the newest version 8 of PHP.

Comment: So you installed Symfony and then added additional code to it?  Because Symfony itself only need 7.2.5 currently.